# Reported speech or no?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

Why in the sentence like this:"John called and told me he is on his way.He should be here soon",-there is no the reported speech, and the verb"is"doesn't change from the present tense form into the past simple form "was" though the word "told" denotes speaking and stands in the past form?

Comment: This question will need to be edited (by me or another user) for readability, so can you clarify what you mean by "there is no the reported speech"?

Comment: Reported speech would be 'John called and told me _that he was_ on his way'.

Comment: Also @KateBunting It's reported speech alright. It's the same thing, with *that* elided. *That* can be dropped most times.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I agree with @Kris ... try ell.stackexchange.com  You see: categories like "reported speech" are mainly used for teaching English, but are not needed by native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the telephone call from John has ended and so is in the *past*, it would seem from the sentence that he is still presently on his way. It is quite correct to say:

> John called (past) and told (past) me he is (present) on his way.

Saying that he *was* on his way would be grammatically correct, but it would mean that his journey was over, or that there was some doubt over it.